# How do I prove that the unit disk is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

The definition of a convex set is the following:

> A set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is convex if $\alpha x + (1 − \alpha) y \in \Omega, \forall x, y \in \Omega$ and $\forall \alpha \in [0, 1]$.

With this it should be easy enough to prove that a set is not convex: just find a counterexample. But how do you prove that it *is* convex? How do I do it for the unit disk?

$$\Omega = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$$

Also what exactly does it mean for a set to be convex?

Comment: Just use the definition? Note that the Euclidean norm is positive homogeneous and subadditive. If $\|x\| \le 1, \|y\| \le 1$ then $\|t x + (1-t)y\| \le t \|x\| + (1-t) \|y\| \le 1$.

Comment: It means that for any two points in the set, all points on the line segment joining those points are in the set. Also, unless specified otherwise, you're certainly allowed to use results from elementary geometry. So for the set in question, note that it's a disk.

Comment: quasi thanks that made it a lot clearer. But I'm still not sure how to use the definition to prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If the two points $P=(x_P,y_P)$ and $Q=(x_Q,y_Q)$  are in the set  than we have $x_P^2+y_P^2=x_Q^2+y_Q^2\leq1$ and to prove that the set is convex we use the definition, that gives:
$$
\alpha(x_P,y_P)+(1-\alpha)(x_Q,y_Q) \in \Omega
$$ 
that is:
$$
\left[\alpha x_P+(1-\alpha)x_Q \right]^2+\left[\alpha y_P+(1-\alpha)y_Q \right]^2\leq 1
$$

Can you prove that this is true for all $P,Q$ such that $x_P^2+y_P^2=x_Q^2+y_Q^2\leq1$ and for $\alpha \in [0,1]$?

Note that $x_P^2+y_P^2$ is the square of the norm of the vector $\overrightarrow {OP}$ and use the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) for the vector $\alpha \overrightarrow {OP}+(1-\alpha)\overrightarrow {OQ}$.

Note that this set is a circle of radius $r=1$ center at the origin, that contains the segments joining any two of its points. This is the meaning of the definition of a convex set.

Comment: I managed to prove it but I'm still having trouble writing math expressions on this website. Thanks for the help though

Comment: You can also see a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135481/showing-unit-sphere-is-convex

Answer (score 1):

If one can prove that a given set is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron), then one can conclude that given set is *convex*.

For example, the unit disk can be represented by the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & 0\\ x & 1 & y\\ 0 & y & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_3$$

and, thus, is a (convex) spectrahedron. Note, however, that not all convex sets are spectrahedra.

---

[convex-analysis](/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) [linear-matrix-inequality](/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality) [spectrahedra](/questions/tagged/spectrahedra)